# Set up subdomain in Apache2

Tags: apache

I have a folder `/var/www/forum` in which I have my forum files. I currently access this by going to `xyz.com/forum`. How can I set up apache to allow me to visit `forum.xyz.com` to visit the forum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope it helps

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    DocumentRoot "/Users/user_name/Sites/site/forum"
    ServerName forum.site.ru
    <Directory "/Users/user_name/Sites/site/forum">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/site_error_log"
    CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/site_access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Thanks

Comment: In case of your site in /Users/user_name/Sites/site/ directory

Comment: Thanks, where do I put this?

Comment: In you apache virtual hosts configuration. /etc/apache2/sites-available/forum.site.ru for example.

Comment: Also check this http://superuser.com/questions/454984/how-to-create-subdomains-on-a-name-based-virtualhost

Comment: @VasiaDunaev can you please tell me why my subdomain always serves the root domain webpage? I have 2 virtual hosts setup in `sites-available/mysite.conf`. Subdomain is of format `admin.domain.com` that should serve page from `var/www/admin` while root domain should server page from `var/www/domain`. Thanks.